# ASP.NET MVC app on IIS7 with WebForms content is throwing NTLM authenticate box

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ntlm

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that also contains some WebForms content (for SSRS ReportViewer). This is deployed to IIS7 and the MVC pages of the app work fine, but when I try to browse to the aspx page I am prompted with the NTLM auth box. I do not have NTLM enabled, I only have Anonymous auth enabled.

I have this deployed and fully working on an IIS6 box, the only other difference is that the IIS6 box is in our company domain, but the IIS7 box is not (I fail to see how this could be the issue as the MVC stuff is working fine).

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I dumped a straight HTML into the same directory and get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Windows Authentication mode along with Anonymous Authentication.